# Restore scroll position after mobile menu is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a mobile menu that opens and closes using jquery by adding a css class that has display:block while the menu div has display:none.
The jquery code has a part where it is supposed to close the menu when a click is registered outside the menu div. Everything works execept the: `$("body").scrollTop(scrollpos)` . This was supposed to scroll the user back where he left off after the `scrollTop(0)` took place and the menu has closed, but it does not scroll at all the scroll is stuck at the top. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/mufwwudj/

```
$(function () {
    var menutoggle = $(".menu-toggle");
    var sidenav = $(".side-nav");

    menutoggle.click(function () {
        var scrollpos = $('body').scrollTop();
        if (!$("body").hasClass("m-nav-open")) {
            $("body").scrollTop(0).addClass("m-nav-open");
        }
        $(document).mouseup(function (e){
        if (!sidenav.is(e.target) && sidenav.has(e.target).length === 0 && !menutoggle.is(e.target) && menutoggle.has(e.target).length === 0){
                if ($("body").hasClass("m-nav-open")) {
                    $("body").scrollTop(scrollpos).removeClass("m-nav-open");
                }
        }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you share a URL where this problem is reproduced? jsfiddle will work.

Comment: Look the code is something like this: jsfiddle.net/mufwwudj Try to scroll to the "ZZZZZ" before u open the menu then open the menu and close it . Instead of scrolling back to the ZZZZ it stays on top

Comment: On which browser are you checking this. Your code works for me at first attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem here is that you are assigning a new mouseup event every time the menutoggle.click function runs.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    if (!sidenav.is(e.target) && sidenav.has(e.target).length === 0 && !menutoggle.is(e.target) && menutoggle.has(e.target).length === 0){
        if ($("body").hasClass("m-nav-open")) {
            $("body").scrollTop(scrollpos).removeClass("m-nav-open");
        }
    }
});
```

Only the first one passes the conditional, even though each one will fire and scrollpos will always equal whatever it was in the first mouseup event listener.

I don't know how you are testing it, or what the HTML looks like but if you are at the top of the page the first time you click it, scrollpos in the mouseup event will always be 0.

Try assigning the mouseup event once, and putting scrollpos outside both so it can be accessed in both.

```
$(function () {
    var menutoggle = $(".menu-toggle");
    var sidenav = $(".side-nav");
    var scrollpos;

    menutoggle.click(function () {
        scrollpos = $('body').scrollTop();
        if (!$("body").hasClass("m-nav-open")) {
            $("body").scrollTop(0).addClass("m-nav-open");
        }
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function (e){
        if (!sidenav.is(e.target) && sidenav.has(e.target).length === 0 && !menutoggle.is(e.target) && menutoggle.has(e.target).length === 0){
            if ($("body").hasClass("m-nav-open")) {
                $("body").scrollTop(scrollpos).removeClass("m-nav-open");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It still does not work. I will try to do a jfiddle with the html and all and I will post it here

Comment: Look the code is something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mufwwudj/ Try to scroll to the "ZZZZZ" before u open  the menu then open the menu and close it . Instead of scrolling back to the ZZZZ it stays on top.

Comment: It is working for me on Chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version : 50.0.2661.87 m . But you might be on to something because it does work in Edge. But why not in my chrome (windows 10). In IE11 does not scroll top it stays where is scrolled.

Comment: In edge works but only once, it saves the variable and always scroll back to the same position. And for some reson it only works in jsfiddle not on my site.

Comment: I modified it so it only adds the event handle for mouse up once, this stops it always scrolling to the same position as explained in my answer. https://jsfiddle.net/mufwwudj/2/ This also works on Chrome for me  Version 50.0.2661.87 m

Comment: Thank you it works. Another quick question any ideea why if I modify CSS this way: https://jsfiddle.net/mufwwudj/5/ it doesn't work anymore. The thing that changes is that instead of transform:translateX(300px) I used margin-left:300px on the content, and display:block and display:none on the menu when is open and closed.

Comment: You've made `.m-nav-opener` have `position: fixed` so it can't scroll to the original position. If you remove `position: fixed` or rewrite this part `$("body").scrollTop(scrollpos).removeClass("m-nav-open")` as `$("body").removeClass("m-nav-open").scrollTop(scrollpos)` it will work. The code removes the class first, removing `position: fixed` then scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ScrollOnTopo() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0); //It scrolls page at top
    }
```

This function may be useful to you.